# HttpClient 4.5.1 - other retry count on multiple Requests

Tags: apache, request, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have a singleton instance of http client and will setting the retry count for every request on execute. Is there a solution?

i only found to set the DefaultHttpRequestRetryHandler globaly in the httpClientBuilder.

```
httpClientBuilder.setRetryHandler(new DefaultHttpRequestRetryHandler(10, false));
```

but this is for all request identical (10)

Answer (score 1):

One can always a custom context attribute to customize HttpClient behavior

```
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create()
        .setRetryHandler((exception, executionCount, context) -> executionCount < (Integer) context.getAttribute("retry.count"))
        .build();
HttpClientContext clientContext = HttpClientContext.create();
clientContext.setAttribute("retry.count", 4);
HttpGet get1 = new HttpGet("http://host/");
try (CloseableHttpResponse response1 = httpClient.execute(get1)) {
    EntityUtils.consume(response1.getEntity());
}
clientContext.setAttribute("retry.count", 10);
HttpGet get2 = new HttpGet("http://host/");
try (CloseableHttpResponse response2 = httpClient.execute(get2)) {
    EntityUtils.consume(response2.getEntity());
}
```